# Setting up a mesh network across a home complex

Tags: mesh-network

I am in the process of setting up wifi across my home complex. Fiber comes into the main building which is 3 floors, each floor is 1200 sq ft. Need to have full coverage here and I can't run ethernet. There are two more buildings in the complex, a workshop that is about 100 ft away from the main building and a guest house that is about 300 ft away. Again, it's not possible to run ethernet to these other buildings so it needs to be all wireless.

I'm looking for advice on what mesh network setup would be most suited for something like this. Can I have a mesh network in the main building but then use some kind of directional antennas to reach the other buildings and put additional mesh nodes there too?